# android cordova app trigger update programmatically

Tags: android, cordova, auto-update

i use this code to download an apk from my localhost

```
function downloadApkAndroid(data) {
var fileURL = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/Download/";

var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI(data);

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function (entry) {

        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);

        promptForUpdateAndroid(entry);
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {

    }
);
```

}

i got success to donwload then it will call this function `promptForUpdateAndroid(entry);` to try install it which the function contain this

```
function promptForUpdateAndroid(entry) {
console.log(entry);
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
        action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
        url: entry.toURL(),
        type: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
    },
    function () {
    },
    function () {
        alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent.');
        console.log("Failed to open URL via Android Intent. URL: " + entry.fullPath);
    }
);
```

}

after it call that function i got alert

> Parse error - there was a problem parsing the package

what i think is the fileURL `var fileURL = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/Download/";` is wrong but i dont really know what is actually the path is. please help me

Comment: i found the file downloaded from server here ///data/user/0/com.app.nEnhance/files/files/path/to/android.apk when i try to click install i got same error which is parse error..

Answer (score 0):

ok i fix my problem already. i put in here incase someone got same problem. its true that path i put is wrong actually because i got the apk i download form server but cant install it becaue it didnt have permission since it puth at the root user so i change the path to

`var fileURL = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory+'android.apk'`

then after it successfully download the file web intent will automatically prompt user to install or not.